# Is floor function an algebraic function?

Tags: calculus

> An algebraic function is a function that can be defined as the root of a polynomial equation.

Is floor function an algebraic function?

Comment: No, it's discontinuous, but roots of a polynomial vary continuously.

Comment: No. If it were the root of a polynomial equation, it would be a continuous function of the coefficients of the polynomial

Comment: No. if it were algebriac, then so would $\lfloor x\rfloor -x$ be algebraic, so a nonzero polynomial with infinitely many roots.